# How can I control Manipulate slider bars with an external device?

Tags: manipulate, slider

I have lots of interactive graphics and I want to control the parameters of the Manipulate[...] with a Griffin USB PowerMate plugged in. I tried

```
ControllerManipulate[
 Plot[Cos[a x], {x, 0, 5}], 
 "Griffin PowerMate" -> {a, 1, 5, .1}]
```

But no luck. Any suggestions?

Dan Bach the Math Jock: 
code@dansmath.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to change your outside hardware...arduino and Mathematica seem to work half decently with each other...here is a nice post with many examples

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/315748

Edit: or atleast it may give you a suggestion to why yours currently isn't working.